# checkall / un-checkall check boxes with js

Tags: javascript

Trying to get a little help with this js code, it is supposed to check and un-check all boxes by ticking the top checkbox. It is old code which I am trying to revive and I am a complete novice to js but willing to learn. I tried several online code checkers but they didnt make any sense to me.

```js
function toggleChecks(field){
  if(document.myform.toggleAll.checked == true){
      for(i=0; i < field.length; i++){
          field[i].checked = true;
      }
  } else {
      for(i=0; i < field.length; i++){
          field[i].checked = false;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="s-12 l-five">
    <div class="box chkBox" style="background-color: #CCC;"><input name ="toggleAll" id ="toggleAll" type ="checkbox" onclick ="toggleChecks(document.myform.cb)"/></div>
</div>
<div class="s-12 l-five">
    <div class="box chkBox"><input name ="toggleAll" id ="toggleAll" type ="checkbox" onclick ="toggleChecks(document.myform.cb)"/></div>
</div>
<div class="s-12 l-five">
    <div class="box chkBox"><input name ="toggleAll" id ="toggleAll" type ="checkbox" onclick ="toggleChecks(document.myform.cb)"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the check boxes and listen for a click on the first checkbox, check/uncheck all the check boxes according to the status of the first check box

```js
const field = document.querySelectorAll('input[type ="checkbox"]');

function toggleChecks(){
  if(event.target.checked){
      for(i=0; i < field.length; i++){
          field[i].checked = true;
      }
  } else {
      for(i=0; i < field.length; i++){
          field[i].checked = false;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="s-12 l-five">
  <div class="box chkBox" style="background-color: #CCC;"><input name ="toggleAll" id ="toggleAll" type ="checkbox" onclick ="toggleChecks()"/></div>
</div>
<div class="s-12 l-five">
  <div class="box chkBox"><input name ="toggle" id ="toggle1" type ="checkbox"></div>
</div>
<div class="s-12 l-five">
    <div class="box chkBox"><input name ="toggle" id ="toggle2" type ="checkbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats really strange, It works here but not on my page?

Comment: The problem was I was running it in the <head> section and it didnt like it, I moved it into the body section and it is now working. much appreciated